# How to create custom event and observer?

Tags: magento2, custom, event-observer

I know about how to use Magento 2 core events. But I want to know how to create custom events and how to override the controller.

advance thanks

Comment: Check Details https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-custom-event-magento-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this event name(custom_observer_name) in controller execute method

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'custom_observer_name',
                    [$this->getRequest()->getParams()]
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Steps for Create custom Event Overserver**

Define ur event name in events.xml and Create a class file for same as per below coding.

> Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomObserverMethod.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomObserverMethod implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * custom event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      //logic herer
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="custom_observer_name">
        <observer name="custom_observer_method" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomObserverMethod"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Ref Link: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-observers-in-magento2/

Comment: Check Details info https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-custom-event-magento-2/